# Get word between quotes

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk, grep

I have x lines like this:

```
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046578'.
```

And I need to extract the word between the `revision of '` and `'` in this example the word `CONTRIB_046578`  and if possible count the number of occurrences of that word using `grep`, `sed` or any other command?

Comment: Have you given it any effort at all?

Comment: Are there duplicates regarding the word? Are there other lines inbetween which need to be discarded?

Comment: instead of finding the word between ' ' how can I find te word between: " revision of ' " and " ' "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a very simple awk script to count the occurrences of what's between the quotes:

```
awk -F\' '{c[$2]++} END{for (w in c) print w,c[w]}' file
```

Using @anubhava's test input file:

```
$ cat file
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046572'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046578'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046579'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046570'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046579'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046572'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046579'
$
$ awk -F\' '{c[$2]++} END{for (w in c) print w,c[w]}' file
CONTRIB_046578 1
CONTRIB_046579 3
CONTRIB_046570 1
CONTRIB_046572 2
```

Comment: instead of finding the word between ' ' how can I find te word between: "revision of '" and "'"?

Comment: There's a lot of options depending on what it is in you're input you're trying to avoid false matches on. One way would be `awk -F "(^.*revision of '|'[^']*$)" '{c[$2]++} END{for (w in c) print w,c[w]}' file`. If that doesn't work for you, tell us why and provide a more representative input file.

Answer (score 8):

The cleanest solution is with `grep -Po "(?<=')[^']+(?=')"`

```
$ cat file
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046578'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'foo'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'bar'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046578'

# Print occurences 
$ grep -Po "(?<=')[^']+(?=')" file
CONTRIB_046578
foo
bar
CONTRIB_046578

# Count occurences
$ grep -Pc "(?<=')[^']+(?=')" file
4

# Count unique occurrences 
$ grep -Po "(?<=')[^']+(?=')" file | sort | uniq -c 
2 CONTRIB_046578
1 bar
1 foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one awk script that you can use to extract and count the frequency of each word in single quote:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i ~ /^'"'.*?'"'/ ) cnt[$i]++;}} 
      END {for (a in cnt) {b=a; gsub(/'"'"'/, "", b); print b, cnt[a]}}' infile
```

#### TESTING

```
cat infile
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046572'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046578'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046579'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046570'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046579'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046572'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046579'
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i ~ /^'"'.*?'"'/ ) cnt[$i]++;}} 
      END {for (a in cnt) {b=a; gsub(/'"'"'/, "", b); print b, cnt[a]}}' infile

CONTRIB_046579 3
CONTRIB_046578 1
CONTRIB_046570 1
CONTRIB_046572 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- Each word can occur multpiple times, and OP wants to count the number of occurrences of each word.
- There are no other lines in the file

**Input file:**

```
$ cat test.txt 
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046578'.
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046572'.
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046579'.
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046570'.
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046572'.
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046578'.
```

**Shell script to filter and count the words:**

```
$ sed "s/.*'\(.*\)'.*/\1/" test.txt | sort | uniq -c
  1 CONTRIB_046570
  2 CONTRIB_046572
  2 CONTRIB_046578
  1 CONTRIB_046579
```

Comment: Segmentation fault error. there is other lines in te file, by the way the search should be between " revision of ' " and " ' ".

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.*\'(.*?)\'.*/$1/' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If the test file below is representative of the file in the actual problem then the following may be useful.

*On the basis that each line in the test file is homogeneous* - that is, well-formatted and containing 8 columns (or fields) - a handy solution using the `cut` command would be as follows:

**file:**

```
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046572'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046578'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046579'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046570'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046579'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046572'
Unable to find latest released revision of 'CONTRIB_046579'
```

**Code:**

```
cut -d ' ' -f 8 file | tr -d "'" | sort | uniq -c
```

**Output:**

```
1 CONTRIB_046570
2 CONTRIB_046572
1 CONTRIB_046578
3 CONTRIB_046579
```

Note on the code: the default delimiter used by `cut` to separate each field is `tab`, but since we require the delimiter to be a single space to separate each field, we specify the option `-d ' '`. The rest of the code is similar to other answers, so I won't repeat what's been said.

General note: this code will probably not reach the desired output if the file is not well-formatted as I already mentioned above.